# Searching For Nested Object in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a problem searching for a nested array in my Angular app. I have to access the package.name. Please help thanksenfoiewfhfofhfowfoewhfowfoewhfwefwfhowefweofhew8ofwofhewofw8eofhwf

**JSON**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Yeah",
    "package_id": 1,
    "price": 100,
    "package": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Yeah"
    }
}]
```

**TS**

```
search(event) {
    const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    if (!val) {
        this.users = this.tempUsers;
    }

    const temp = this.tempUsers.filter((row) => {
        return Object.keys(row).some((property) => {
            return row[property] === null ? null : row[property].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1;
        });
    });

    this.users = temp;
}
```

> TS

```
 getAllUsers() {
    this.usersService.getAll()
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.users = data.Users;
          this.tempUsers= [...this.users];
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

Comment: It is not even nested!! It's an object inside array. If your array always contains only 1 element then you can do array[0].package.name if not loop through it and access

Comment: @PratapA.K. How can i access the package.name since i can only search for the name, package_id and price?

Comment: Is your array always contains 1 element or more than 1?

Comment: @PratapA.K. I mean this.tempUsers = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Yeah",
      "package_id": 1,
      "price": 100,
      "package": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Yeah"
      }
    }
 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you,

```
const temp = this.tempUsers.filter((row) => {
  return Object.keys(row).some((property) => {
    if (property === 'package') {
      // check package.name value here
      // like return row[property].name === 'something' ? true : false;
    } else {
    // the rest of the outer properties can be checked here
    // not modifying your code here, but make sure it works for you
    return row[property] === null ? null : row[property].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1;
    }
  });
});
```

I have only answered your question on how to access the nested object inside the array method. Hope it helps or gives you an idea to fine tune your solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to your data, You can use the following filter;

```
const filteredData = data.filter((item) => item.price.toString() === val || item.package_id.toString() === val || item.package.name.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 );
```

// UPDATED WITH CODE

```
search(event) {
    const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
   const filteredData = this.users.filter((item) => item.price.toString() === val || 
   item.package_id.toString() === val || 
    item.package.name.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 );

    this.users = filteredData ;
}
```

Comment: How about the name, package_id, price? I need to search that too.

Comment: So is it a or comparision ? val is either equal to package_id or price or name ?

Comment: Yes it needs to search all of them including the package.name

Comment: Updated my comment to add those parameters

Comment: Done, try it out

Comment: Its not searching

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180668/discussion-between-nightraiser-and-gray-singh).